# UWP app throws Access is Denied when using Native WiFi API

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-standard

We are developing a dotnet standard library and one of the features we need is scanning WiFi.
For managing the Native Wifi API we use the following library: https://github.com/emoacht/ManagedNativeWifi.

Everything works fine when we import our library in a console application.

When we import our library with an UWP app we always get the following error:

```
{"MethodName: WlanOpenHandle, ErrorCode: 5, ErrorMessage: Access is denied.\r\n"}
```

We have following capabilities:

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="wiFiControl" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the library you shared, and I found that it uses [Win32 Native WiFi API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanconnect#requirements). You can find the requirement(desktop apps only) under the API document, this API only supports desktop apps, **it does not support UWP**.

It is recommended that you use [Windows.Devices.WiFi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifi?view=winrt-22621) from Windows Runtime API in UWP. Here is the official sample [Wi-Fi scanning](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/WiFiScan) for your reference.